# Contain value not working in background size

Tags: css, background-image

This question is very similar to another question, but is not exactly the same in that the code does not have the background shortcut code, but uses the individual rules.

Notes about the layers
Layer 1 is an inline style created by PHP
Layer 2 is my attempt to add the contain value to the layer in the child theme without overriding the PHP. 
Layer 3 is the parent theme assigning the cover value to the layer. In Firefox Inspector, the background-size rule shows as being crossed out.
Layer 4 is also part of the parent theme.

```
element 
{
    background-image: url(https://montanawebmaster.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Bug.jpg);
}

#masthead .header-image 
{
    background-size: contain;
}

#masthead .header-image 
{
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.kahuna-cropped-headerimage div.header-image 
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is affecting several sites using the parent theme, but here is an example: https://montanawebmaster.com/images/why-is-the-wordpress-kahuna-theme-messing-with-my-images/ The bug image in the banner should be contained as opposed to cover.

Comment: Looking again, the `background-position` and `background-attachment` are also affecting the looks of the image, you should avoid repating the background and position it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the `background-attachment: fixed`.

You'll need to update your css to:

```
#masthead .header-image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: unset;
}
```

With this new change, you may or may not want to set it back to `cover`.

Comment: That had exactly the desired effect! There are other issues with the strategy of using the same image for a very horizontal banner as for a content image, but those issues are planning not coding.

Comment: Glad to be of help!